# Facebook App Link not working with Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to use Facebook App Link along with Firebase Dynamic Link. But there is a problem when I use them together.

In the first case, only Facebook App Link is used like the code below:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="comexamplescheme"/>
</intent-filter>
```

My app is open when I click on the link in Facebook App, so this case is worked.

In the second one, Facebook App Link is used with Firebase Dynamic Link like the below:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="comexamplescheme"/>

            <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This code only works with Firebase Dynamic Link. My app now is unable to open from Facebook App.

I guess the problem may be caused by there are more than one scheme. Is there any idea to use these deep links together?

Comment: Did you find out what was the reason Facebook links didn't work?